# Can a Boy of Silence be killed?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

If you startle him, a Boy of Silence sends his dwarfish minions to attack you and vanishes. Can a Boy of Silence be killed before he detects you and runs away?

I have tried and failed, but perhaps more skilled players than I have had better luck... If you're one of them, please share your trick.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can kill them, but you can either avoid them (as explained in @Cole's answer), or you can prepare a Devil's Kiss trap on a doorway, startle the BoS, run through your trap, then watch as the minions die from the trap (then kill any stragglers left). In short: the BoS have never been a serious threat to me, and I've been playing on Hard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuI3jtNNDrM). It seems that Boys of Silence *can* be killed!

[image]

The steps outlined in the video are as follows.

1. Equip the *Spectral Sidekick* Gear.
2. Find a spare weapon.
3. Drop/pick up the spare weapon until the gun has a clear line of sight to the Boy of Silence.
4. Get the Boy of Silence to turn towards you with a yellow light.
5. Take cover and let your "ghostly ally" hit the Boy of Silence.
6. Repeat step 4-5 until the Boy of Silence dies; if the effects of Spectral Sidekick end before the Boy of Silence dies, go back to step 3.
7. Do an Irish jig over his dead body.

Some notes:

- The description for this Gear is "Dropping a weapon creates a ghostly ally for a few seconds".
- In the video linked to above, which shows a part the level called "The Atrium", there is a weapon lying in front of some crates on the left, in the room right after that with all the Motorized-Patriot masks, just before you encounter the first Boy of Silence in the game.

**Edit**: here is an alternative method applicable to (SPOILER)...

> the Boy of Silence that sneaks up on you just before you rescue Elizabeth from her tormentors, near the end of the game.

Just one-shot the Boy of Silence (in the mouth, if that matters) with the shotgun, as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqoz6F0d5O0#t=40s); which difficulty level is used in the video is unknown, though.

Comment: Since this is on PC, I was skeptical at first because people can mod certain things and modify system files that other console individuals can't, BUT, I don't think that anyone would've thought of using a spectral gear perk to 'kill' the boy of silence. Consider making a step-by-step to kill the B.o.S for this question. Great find!

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 Great edit!

Answer (score 6):

> Well, it is not so easy to kill boys of silence in Bioshock Infinite. Boys of silence are impervious to damage and will immediately sound the alarm. However, you can bypass them completely in Bioshock Infinite. As Boys of Silence can only see whatever their masks illuminate, you need just walk outside of their range of vision won't attract their ire in Bioshock Infinite. --nancy8930 of pubarticles

[Source](http://answers.pubarticles.com/82360,how-to-kill-boys-of-silence-in-bioshock-infinite-tips-1365758122.html)

Personally I haven't had any luck at killing them on easy. So reading that they are invulnerable I pretty have found out why.